# Why Hive SQL returning NULL values for a particular column in Select statement when that column has all double values?

Tags: sql, join, hive, left-join, hiveql

I'm using Hive SQL.  Version is Hive 1.1.0-cdh5.14.0.  In my example below, sp.close is a column with type double values.  I checked sp.column and there are definitely no NULL values.  Yet, in this select statement below, sp.close shows all NULL values.  Why?

```
select
    step1.*,
    sp.close

from
    step1 left join stockprices2 sp on (
        step1.symbol = sp.symbol and
        step1.year = sp.year and
        step1.startmonth = sp.month and
        step1.startday = sp.day and
        step1.sector = sp.sector
    )

;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, your `left join` did not find a matchin row in `stockprices2`. In that event, the row from `step1` is retained, but all columns from `stockprices2` will be `null` in the resultset. This is by design how the database signals that the `left join` came up empty.

You can easily verify that by just chaning the `left join` to an `inner join`: you should have less rows returned (where there is no match in `stockprices2`, the row from `step1` is removed from the resultset), and no `null` values in `sp.close`.

Or you can add one of the columns used in the `left join` conditions in the `select` clause, and see that it's `null` too.

```
select
    st.*,
    sp.close,
    sp.symbol   -- null too
from step1 st 
left join stockprices2 sp 
    on  st.symbol = sp.symbol 
    and st.year = sp.year 
    and st.startmonth = sp.month 
    and st.startday = sp.day 
    and st.sector = sp.sector
```

Side note: the parentheses around the join conditions are superfluous.

Comment: That was it.  Seems obvious in retrospect.  Thanks!